# How do you add 2 decimal places to numbers?

Tags: c++, decimal

This is my code. The information my professor gave us to only show 2 decimal points is out.precision(2) ;.

```
cout << "Welcome to the Book Store" << endl << endl;

cout << "Enter the single copy price: $" ;
cin >> single_copy_price ;

cout << "Enter the number of books sold: " ;
cin >> num_of_books_sold ;

cout << "Enter the discount percentage: " ;
cin >> discount_percentage ;

cout << "********************************************" << endl ;

subtotal = single_copy_price * num_of_books_sold ;
cout.precision(2) ;
cout<< "Subtotal: $" << subtotal << endl ;

cout << "Discount percentage: " << discount_percentage << "%" << endl ;

discount_ammount = subtotal * (discount_percentage / 100) ;
cout.precision(2) ;
cout << "Discount ammount: $ " <<  discount_ammount << endl ;

cout.precision(2) ;
cout << "Final price: $" << subtotal - discount_ammount << endl ;

return 0;
```

### `

However, this is my result:

Welcome to the Book Store

Enter the single copy price: $10.50
Enter the number of books sold: 20
Enter the discount percentage: 15

---

Subtotal: $2.1e+02
Discount percentage: 15%
Discount ammount: $ 32
Final price: $1.8e+02
Program ended with exit code: 0

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the `cout.setprecision(2)`.  What it does is limit the number of significant figures in a number displayed.  It's useful for scientific work, but not what you are looking for.

One person's solution was to write their own formatting method: http://www.arachnoid.com/cpptutor/student3.html

At the very end is point 6, for currency.  His solution also formats with $ and commas for thousands places.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void showCurrency(double dv, int width = 14)
{
    const string radix = ".";
    const string thousands = ",";
    const string unit = "$";
    unsigned long v = (unsigned long) ((dv * 100.0) + .5);
    string fmt,digit;
    int i = -2;
    do {
        if(i == 0) {
            fmt = radix + fmt;
        }
        if((i > 0) && (!(i % 3))) {
            fmt = thousands + fmt;
        }
        digit = (v % 10) + '0';
        fmt = digit + fmt;
        v /= 10;
        i++;
    }
    while((v) || (i < 1));
    cout << unit << setw(width) << fmt.c_str() << endl;
}
```

The most simple solution is to set your precision to 2 more than the number of digits in the integer portion.  To figure that out, cast to int and count the number of times you can divide by 10 with a non-zero result.